# How to post image into database column and show it on page?

Tags: php, mysql, image-uploading

I'm gonna insert image file name in registration page into my existing database and table and show it on page.

table name in mysql is: **patient_tbl** and column is **avatar**

Here is sample code which is available on [w3schools](http://w3schools.in/demo/image_upload_and_generate_thumbnail_using_ajax_in_php/)

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="image_upload_demo_submit.php" method="post" name="image_upload_form" id="image_upload_form">
<div id="imgArea"><img src="./img/default.jpg">
  <div class="progressBar">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="percent">0%</div>
  </div>
  <div id="imgChange"><span>Change Photo</span>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="image_upload_file" id="image_upload_file">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is also my input data for avatar that it's currently working as text input.

```
<input rows="3" cols="30" id="avatar" name="avatar" value="" type="text">
```

> what should I add into this form or in the **functions.php** that
>   image name will be posted into my **Avatar** column ?
>
> How to show it on page as img src ?

Here's also [function.php](http://allinworld99.blogspot.my/2015/01/php-profile-image-upload-script-change.html?showComment=1448260413911#c6998418339124525751)

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is only the HTML-part of the code. What have you tried in PHP?

Comment: Also, in many cases, it is a better choice to store the file on the server, and store a reference to the file in your database.

Comment: I already updated my question, please have a look into that sample. in the function.php

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to get image name on server, you can store image name in text input,but for image src you have to save it on server and make client img src to server image, I tried this code on FireFox, you can try it

```js
function getName(elem){
var img=document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]
var imgname=document.getElementById("imgname")
if(elem.files.length==0)
{
    imgname.value=""
    img.src="./img/default.jpg"
    return
}
var file=elem.files[0]
imgname.value=file.name
var src = URL.createObjectURL(file)
img.src=src
}
```

```html
<div id="imgArea"><img src="./img/default.jpg">
  <div class="progressBar">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="percent">0%</div>
  </div>
  <div>
  <span>
  Image Name
  </span>
    <input type="text" id="imgname" />
 </div>
  <div id="imgChange"><span>Change Photo</span>
  
    <input type="file" onchange="getName(this)" accept="image/*" name="image_upload_file" id="image_upload_file">
 <br/>
 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this method doesn't work cause it will get real path file name, as you can see in my function, the file name will be renamed after upload that's why it won't get the file name to show it on page. based on my function, we need to find a way to get renamed file after upload completed.

Comment: you can send data by ajax and make response as json object contains data after inserted or updated